# Problems with a modeling cloth add-on

Tags: add-on, cloth-simulation

I'm having problems trying to run this addon
https://bitbucket.org/nitish_116/tri3d_gazer
After following the steps in this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSOrc_rPAnM 
the console show this error

```
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
found bundled python: C:\Users\User\blender-2.79-windows64\2.79\python
Read blend: C:\Users\User\Desktop\gazer.blend
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\gazer.blend\Text", line 11, in <module>
  File "/tri3d_gazer/operators/gazer_create_garment.py", line 53, in <module>
    class CreateGarment(bpy.types.Operator):
  File "/tri3d_gazer/operators/gazer_create_garment.py", line 59, in CreateGarment
    g_folder_name = generate_garment_folder_name()
  File "/tri3d_gazer/operators/gazer_create_garment.py", line 45, in generate_garment_folder_name
    if cur_garment_name not in os.listdir(dir_name):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The System Cannot Find The Path Specified: '/settings_config/'
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

The folder is there and I don't know why the addon do this, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Better contact the author of the addon. It is probably a problem with the path format.

Comment: Ty for the answer, I was hoping that were a common trouble easy to fix or some mistake in the installation, anyhow I'll try with the author in youtube or in the valentina-project.org forums later, seems like the addon comes from there ...

Comment: I'm not sure if Blender changes it in this case, but /settings_config/ should use backslashes (as you use Windows). If it's hardcoded into the addon you will need to find place in the code and resave it with \settings_config etc